# awk Repeat the values of a column n times

Tags: awk

I have a column and I want to repeat it multiple times.

eg
for example I want the following column

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

to repeat n times and become

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
etc
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 3 with any value of `n` and `$1` with the column you want to print:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do awk '{print $1}' file; done
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

You could do it just with `awk` but you would have to store the whole file in memory:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$1}END{for(i=1;i<=3;i++)for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)print a[j]}' file
```

This is one of those occasions were using the shell constructs actually makes sense.

Comment: Also `cat file` instead the `awk` command. **EDIT**: Sorry, he speaks about columns, then `awk` better.

Comment: @Birei I assume that when the OP asks to print a single column they mean 1 column in a file which has many i.e. `awk` could be replaced by `cut` but not `cat`. If of course the file only contains a single column then `cat` is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v n=7 '{s = s $1 ORS} END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", s}' file
```

Set `n` to whatever number you like.

Alternatively, with GNU awk:

```
awk -v n=7 -v RS='\0' -v ORS= 'END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print}' file
```

Comment: The second approach is clever but assumes that file contains only a single column *(which may actually be the case and the OP's description is poor).*

Comment: @sudo_O yeah, I'm not putting a whole lot of thought into this one yet as I fully expect the next few responses from the OP to be "oh, but my input doesn't REALLY look like that....".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a portable `awk`-based solution to do it using only built in variables with no looping at all :

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF += __-(OFS = $-_)^_' RS='^$' FS='^$' ORS= __=3

1 <<<<
2
3
4
1 <<<<
2
3
4
1 <<<<
2
3
4
```

To repeat each row **N times consecutively** before the next row, then do

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF += __-(OFS = "\n" $-_)^_' FS='^$' __=3

1 <<<<
1 <<<<
1 <<<<
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
```

If you wanna duplicate **each row horizontally** by **N** times, it's the same concept, slightly different :

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF = __ *(OFS = $-_)^_' FS='^$' __=7

10101010101010
11111111111111
12121212121212
13131313131313
14141414141414
15151515151515
16161616161616
17171717171717
18181818181818
19191919191919
```

You can even make cute numeric pyramids by having the repeat count be based on `NR` :

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF = NR * (OFS=$-_)^_' FS='^$'
10
1111
121212
13131313
1414141414
151515151515
16161616161616
1717171717171717
181818181818181818
19191919191919191919
2020202020202020202020
```

So if you ever need `2^25` aka `32^5` copies for `ASCII` string of `2^25` itself, then here's a pretty quick (**`0.45s`**) and easy way to get it done with no loops at all :

```
out9:  256MiB 0:00:00 [ 591MiB/s] [ 591MiB/s] [  <=> ]

( echo 33554432 | mawk2 'NF=(OFS=$-_)^_*$-_' FS='^$'; )  

0.30s user 0.10s system 89% cpu 0.454 total

      1 268435457
```

Even if you wanna repeat pretty sizable files, it's reasonably speedy fast : e.g. less than `13 secs` for **`9 x`** a `1.85 GB` file :

```
 {m,g}awk 'NF += __-(OFS = $-_)^_' RS='^$' FS='^$' ORS= __=9

 out9: 16.6GiB 0:00:12 [1.30GiB/s] [1.30GiB/s] [ <=> ]
  in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.42GiB/s] [3.42GiB/s] [========>] 100%            

  5.48s user 4.44s system 77% cpu 12.809 total

  112448475 17851902237 17851902237
```

If that's too slow for your needs, perhaps this way is a bit faster :

```
 {m,g}awk '
 BEGIN { FS = RS = "^$" }{__=sprintf("%*s",__, OFS = ORS = _)
         gsub(".", "\\&", __) }   sub(".+",__)'  __=9 


  in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.48GiB/s] [3.48GiB/s] [========>] 100%            
 out9: 16.6GiB 0:00:07 [2.12GiB/s] [2.12GiB/s] [ <=> ]

 ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 -v __=9 ; )
 0.72s user 4.34s system 64% cpu 7.855 total

 112448475 17851902237 17851902237
```